# Sheaf of sections of vector bundle over a manifold is an $\mathcal O_M$-module

Tags: sheaf-theory, vector-bundles

Section 13.1.2 of Ravi Vakil: "Fix a rank $n$ vector bundle $\pi:V\rightarrow M$. The sheaf of sections $F$ of $V$ is an $\mathcal O_M$-module - given any open set $U$, we can multiply a section over $U$ by a function on $U$ and get another section."

I don't understand what's going on here. A section of $F$ over $U$ is a function $s:U\rightarrow M$ with $\pi s=\iota:U\subset M$. What is meant by a "function on $U$ and how does multiplying by one yield another set theoretic section of $\pi$?

Comment: A function on $U$ is a function $f : U \to \mathbb{R}$. You can multiply such a thing by a section $s$ pointwise, and the claim is that this produces another section $fs$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan so to multiply I need to use the fact $M$ is locally Euclidean? I still don't see how $fs$ would be a section of $\pi$..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a vector bundle $\pi:V\to M$, if you take any 'vector' $v\in V$, then this vector is 'over' a point $p:=\pi(v)$, i.e. $v$ is in the fibre $\pi^{-1}(p)$, which is assumed to be a vector space on its own, so that $\lambda\cdot v$ makes sense for any $\lambda\in\Bbb R$, and *is in the same fibre*.

So, if we have a section $s:U\to V$ with $U\subset M$, and a function $f:U\to\Bbb R$, then $x\mapsto f(x)\cdot s(x)$ makes sense and is also a section, as
$$\pi(f(x)\cdot s(x))=\pi(s(x)) = x$$
by the above argument.

Comment: Really clear, thanks. So we don't need the manifold structure, just the sheaf of continuous functions, right?